# UITableviewcell problem

Tags: iphone

I have uiviewcontroller classes in that class i addded uitableview ...I can able to reload data .But some times my tableview cell is not visible ....

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to understand about UITableViews is that they're easiest to make work if you overload the UITableview controller.  This gives you access to 3 crucial functions: rowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath, and didSelectRowAtIndexPath. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, which is called once for every cell in your table, you should be able to set it up however you want.

If your question is more about reloading your table data, use reloadData, and then you should get cellForRowAtIndexPath calls, once for each cell, yet again.

Please attempt to clarify your question, it's hard to tell what you're having trouble with. Please download the available samples, also, since there really is nothing that isn't already coded.

Comment: I agree, partly.  A reasonable alternative is to use the base UITableViewController, but create custom delegates and dataSources.  The biggest problem with that approach is that you now have two custom classes, instead of just one, and that each must have information about the data set upon which the table is based.  On the other hand, you have more separation of concerns.

Comment: It is possible to have a single custom object be both delegates by having your custom class implement both delegate protocols.